# Task Scheduler website/app that works with 30 minute intervals

Tags: android, web-apps

I am searching for a task scheduler where I can configure the intervals for one day. For example I could configure one day to be split up into 30 minute intervals each, and select a task for each of those 30 minute interval sets.

Example:

> Monday
>
> 09:30 - 10:00 | Do something outside
>
> 10:00 - 10:30 | Do something inside
>
> 17:30 - 18:00 | Sleep

It'd be nice if it had a calendar style view like calendar.google.com. When I click on one day/entry I wanna see the day that is split up into the upper stated intervals

I don't care whether this is a mobile phone app (aslong as its available for android) or a website (that is accessible via mobile phone if possible.)

Comment: Android already has a Calendar app that allows you to enter events with a date and time. It has a Month, Week and Day view. The Day view shows the hours of the day and the events scheduled. What other functionality do you need?

Comment: @BillW Id love if it had that specific interval feature so I can basically cut my day into the intervals described above. Then I just click on one interval for example 09:30 - 10:00 and it lets me enter some specific task I do in that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a sample task on [Hitask](https://hitask.com) to see if it can manage tasks like yours. It turns out that it can. Also, has a Google Calendar integration. Check the image down below to see the functionality.

[image]

Comment: This looks actually quite promising. Thank you for taking the time to check it out.